# Should I use "be" in a conditional?

Tags: conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs, subjunctives

I have read in some documents that they, for example, say:

> 1. If you **be** here, it would be great.

I touch the meaning, well; but I would like to become sure if these two sentences have two different meanings:

> 2. If you **be** here, it would be great.
> 3. If you **are** here, it would be great.

I suppose that in the first one being here is the suggestion of speaker; but in the second, it is the suggestion of listener or it is the default case.

Am I true?

Comment: "It would be great if you **were** here" would seem quite natural in this sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you **be** here* is no longer used in English, although it was fairly common in Early Modern English, around 1700, and was still in poetic and rhetorical use into the 19th century:

> If music **be** the food of love, play on. —Shakespeare, *Twelfth Night*, ca. 1601
>
> If this **be** treason, make the most of it! —*attributed (probably falsely) to* Patrick Henry, 1765

Today we use ordinary indicatives for a likely event, or *irrealis* past forms (with no inflection for first or third person singular) for an event regarded as merely possible, or unlikely:

> If you **are** here it **will** be great.  ... If he **is** here it **will** be great.
>    *These speak of future events held to be quite possible, even probable.*
>
> If you **were** here it **would** be great.  ... If he **were** here it **would** be great.
>     *These may speak of either a present non-fact or a future doubtful possibility.*

It is common in colloquial English to use Simple Past forms in the *if* clause alongside *would* in the consequence clause—*If he **was** here it **would** be great*—because *would* is no longer restricted to low probabilities. This use is now deprecated in formal English, but is likely to become acceptable over the next generation or so.

Comment: So with something like *"It would be great if he **was** here tomorrow"*, is there anything wrong with it? That is, is that acceptable now in today's standard English?

Comment: @F.E. It's fine in conversation, and it's not the sort of utterance that shows up in academic or bureaucratic English. But the more formal registers like you to make up your mind how tentatively you're advancing a proposition and mark it on both ends of the conditional.

Comment: Isn't the preterite "was" in that example being used for modal remoteness? That is, isn't this similar to *"It would be great if he **arrived** here tomorrow"*, with "arrived" being used as a modal preterite?

Comment: @F.E. But "modal remoteness" (not a term I particularly care for) is so to speak 'graded' with *BE* in 1sg/3sg: *was/were*; and as I said, formal English is still uncomfortable with the fully-inflected preterite.

Comment: What do you mean by "graded"? For modal remoteness, can't the preterites forms in *BE* be used for all the persons and numbers, just as they are for other verbs?

Comment: @F.E. They can; feel free to use them that way; but  if you write *if he was* in a hypothetical or counterfactual conditional it won't go over well with highschool English teachers, Comp 101 TAs, LitCrit dissertation advisors or PMLA editors. ... NOte by the way that none of the other verbs has distinct inflections for 1sg and 3sg in the preterite, so it doesn't arise there.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the competence of those "high school English teachers, Comp 101 TAs, LitCrit dissertation advisors"?

Comment: The other verbs only have the preterite forms to show this modal remoteness, but the verb BE has two ways: the modal preterite use, and (for 1st and 3rd person singular) the *irrealis* "were".

Comment: @F.E. Prescriptivist sneers? You will have to turn in your linguistics union card! It's a dialect, and like all dialects it has its own grammar.

Comment: What dialect? I'm talking about standard English. Oh, you mean those people who think only the irrealis "were" is acceptable are using a dialect/register! (That I could probably agree with.)

Comment: @F.E. No, I'm talking about linguistic facts on the ground: what academic/legal/formal prose prefers. It's changing - it always has been - but it has not adopted the *If I was you* style yet. ... And what is "standard" English?

Comment: Perhaps some registers have a style that prefers the use of irrealis "were" when possible, but the modal remoteness use of preterite forms of BE have been commonly in use for a long, long, long time.

Comment: @F.E. I never said they hadn't.

Comment: What is "standard English"? Oh that's relatively easy, more or less, for me to kinda answer. I'm basically basing what is "standard English" on stuff like the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (I'm also using the older 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al.).